# If $\overline{U \cap Z}$ is compact in $\bar U$, how does it follow that $\overline{U \cap Z}$ is compact in $Z$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

From *Intro to Topological Manifolds* by Lee. I am confused about the proof of the closed subset part, which starts at line $4$ of the proof.

If $\overline{U \cap Z}$ is compact in $\bar U$, how does it follow that $\overline{U \cap Z}$ is compact in $Z$?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness is an absolute, not relative property, in the following sense:

(1). A space $W$ is compact iff every cover of $W$ by open subsets of $W$ has a finite sub-cover.

(2). A sub-space $W$ of a space $Y$ is compact in $Y$ iff every cover of $W$ by open sets of $Y$ has a finite sub-cover.

(3). The important point is that a space $W$ is compact iff $W$ is compact in any space $Y$ of which $W$ is a sub-space.

So if $\overline {U\cap Z}$ is compact in $\overline U$ then the   $space $   $\overline {U\cap Z}$ is compact, and it is a sub-space of $\overline Z=Z,$ so it is compact in $Z.$

This implicitly uses (twice) the transitivity of the relation "sub-space": If $B$ is a sub-space of $X$ and if $C$ is a sub$set$ of $B$ then the topology on $C$ as a sub-space of $B$ is equal to the topology on $C$ as a sub-space of $X$.... (With  $C=\overline {U\cap Z}$ and with $B=\overline U$ or with $B=\overline Z$.)

Comment: Sometimes I think it would be useful to have a symbol similar to $\subset,$  like  $\subset_S, $ to denote sub-space, to emphasize  that $B\subset_S A$ means that the topology on $B$ is inherited from the supset $A.$

Comment: But isn't compactness of a subspace $W$ a relative property since we need an open cover by sets open in the main space $Y$?

Comment: Let $W$ be a sub-space of $Y.$... (1). If $W$ is a compact space and $C$ is a cover of $W$ by open subsets of $Y, $ then $\{c\cap W:c\in C\}$ has a finite subset $E$ that covers $W.$  For each $e\in E$  choose $c_e\in C$ such that $c_e\cap W=e.$ Then $\{c_e:e\in E\}$ is a finite sub-cover of $C.$ ...(2). If $W$ is compact in $Y,$ and  $D$ is a cover of $W$ by open subsets of $W$ then for each $d\in D$ choose  an open subset $c_d$  of $Y$ such that $c_c\cap W=d. $ There is a finite $C^*\subset  \{c_d:d\in D\}$  that covers $W,$  so $\{c_d\cap W: c_d\in C^*\}$ is a finite sub-cover of $D. $

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a topological space, if $Y\subset X$, if you consider in $Y$ the subspace topology, and if $K\subset Y$, then $K$ is compact in $Y$ if and only if $K$ is compact in $X$. So, yes, if $\overline{U\cap Z}$ is compact in $U$, then it is also compact in $\overline Z=Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\overline {U \cap Z} $ is covered by $\{V_i \cap Z\}$, $i \in I$ where each $V_i$ is open in $X$. Intersecting with $\overline {U}$ we see that $\overline {U \cap Z} \subset \cup_i \{V_i \cap Z \cap \overline {U}\} \subset \cup_i \{V_i \cap \overline {U}\} $. By hypothesis there is a finite subcover (since the sets in the union are open sets in $\overline {U}$). This gives the desired finite subcover of the original cover since $V_i \cap \overline {U} \subset V_i $.